# How to get data from selected points in Lightning Chart

Tags: lightningchart

In lightning chart i need to get Y axis data(only portion which i have zoomed in),I have used chart with zoom band feature through which i make zoom into the portion,I need data of that zoomed portion,Is there any example of that.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to manually filter the relevant data points from your data set.

The active Axis interval (start -> end) can be requested at any time with [Axis.getInterval](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/axis.html#getinterval) method.

Alternatively, you can trigger actions when an Axis interval changes by using [Axis.onScaleChange](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/axis.html#onscalechange) method.

```
chart.getDefaultAxisX().onScaleChange((start, end) => {
    // This code gets called when X axis interval changes.
    // `start` and `end` variables refer to the active X axis interval range.
})
```

In your case, you should keep a reference to your data set, and when required find all the points whose `x` value lies between X interval start and end values.